Wouldn't photonic computers be larger, not much faster?
I hear a lot about photonic computing as a possible alternative to transistor-based computing. However transistors are already much smaller than the wavelength of optical light. Wouldn't optical logical elements necessarily be much larger, and therefore we wouldn't be able to pack as much circuitry into a device of the same size?
The claimed advantage of optical computing is increased speed, since an optical signal can have much higher bandwidth than an electrical signal. But if devices are much larger, than light delay starts to matter more. For example, consider that if an electronic computer has a clock frequency of $f=$4 GHz, then a signal can propagate at most $d = c/f=$ 7.5 cm in a clock cycle. So if we go optical and things get substantially larger, then light delay starts to limit your clock frequency. Claims of THz-scale computing are particularly confusing; at $f=$ 1 THz, $d=300 \mu m$. Optical wavelengths are around 400 nm, so a signal can only propagate ~1000 circuit elements per clock cycle.
So given the above, would an all-optical computer really be significantly faster than transistor-based computers? Isn't the reduced density of logical circuitry another major disadvantage?

You hit the nail on the head. It is a periodically recurring hype, each time less convincing...

You wouldn't want to build a large-scale, photonic supercomputer, but "computing" is not always large-scale. Sometimes, all you need are a few logic gates, switches, amplifiers, etc. If you happen to need them in a place like a fiber optic network switch, where you already are dealing with optical signals, then photonic "computing" really can be cost effective as compared with a system that converts the signal from optical to electronic and then back again.
